# Display a single columns in while loop using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, echo

I searched a lot still could not find satisfactory answer. Please have a look at the sample mysql table below:

```
id    |    Name        |    Country
1     |    User1       |    India
2     |    User2       |    India
3     |    User3       |    India
4     |    User4       |    Australia
5     |    User5       |    Australia
```

I want to display above table in a while loop using PHP, something like below:

```
Country Name:         |        Total Members From The Country:
India                 |        3
Australia             |        2
```

I only want to target and display only one column/field i.e "country". Can anyone please share the query code here so I can proceed with my work and thank you for  your time.

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Keywords you could search for are `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`. The query then should look something like this:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(*) FROM Users GROUP BY Country;
```

This will group all rows by the value of your `Country` column and count the rows with `COUNT` which will give you a row for each country with the corresponding count in your table.

You are free to extend the query with a `WHERE` to filter for specific countries.

Comment: There could be 10 rows with same country and 20 rows with other country so can I achieve the results I am looking for?

Comment: Yes, thats what `GROUP BY` is for. It will group same values in that column.

Comment: I am still learning, if possible can you please give me the complete code as a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as total_member
FROM your_table
GROUP BY country
```

You should have something like this as result if you fetch an associative array :

```
$result = array(
    0 => array (
        "country" => "India",
        "total_member" => 3

    ),
    1 => array (
        "country" => "Australia",
        "total_member" => 2
    )
);
```

Then just loop throught your result and display what you want :

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['country'] . " | " . $value['total_member'];
}
```

Adapt so it looks like you want !

Is it what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the country field may contain other data as well like other 100 or more country names. So do I need to put everything in array to display through the loop?

Comment: The main point is the query. The idea is just to create a query that will return what you want : the country name and the number of user for each country here :) Once you get the result, you can do what you want ! You can create a html table and use the foreach loop to create row for each country / number of user, you can juste make an echo, etc.

Comment: I tried your code and got this error message "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Comment: I don't use mysqli sorry I use...I just give you the query, you can use it and fetch the result no?

Comment: I dont understand because I am still learning. If possible can you please give me the complete code as a sample.

Comment: If you can't make a simple query I can't help you :/ Just check the doc, it's the bascis ! Build a query can be hard but just fetch some data from database is the step 1 to build dynamic website or other :) And as I said, I don't know mysqli so I won't do the search for you ! With PDO I could help you but not mysqli sorry. Do you have some phpmyadmin or mysqlworbench to test the query solo?